# Printing 3D Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, 3d

I am trying to print arrays before and after they are filled with user given inputs. Therefore, this would be the output if the given size is 3:

> //user inputs values for first matrix
>
> Before adding:
>
> Array [0] =
>
> Array [1] =
>
> Array [2] =
>
> //add user inputs
>
> After adding:
>
> Array [0] =   row 0 = [...]
>
> ```
>             row 1 = [...] 
>
>            ... depending on user given size of the first matrix
> ```
>
> Array[1] =     Array[2] =
>
> //ask for inputs for second matrix
>
> Before Adding
>
> Array [0] =   row 0 = [...]
>
> ```
>             row 1 = [...] 
>
>            ... depending on user given size of the first matrix
> ```
>
> Array[1] =     Array[2] =
>
> After adding
>
> Array [0] =   row 0 = [...]
>
> ```
>           row 1 = [...] 
>
>           ... depending on user given size of the first matrix
> ```
>
> Array[1] = row 0 = [...]
>
> ```
>           row 1 = [...] 
>
>           ... depending on user given size of the first matrix
>    Array[2] =
> ```

I wrote the following code to achieve this (In a class called ThreeDRayRunner):

```
public static void print(int [][][] array)
{
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++ )
    {
        for (int x=0; x<array[i].length;x++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("row "+ x);
            for (int j=0; j<array[i][x].length;j++)
            {
                    System.out.print (array[i][x][j]+ " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

However,I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ThreeDRay.print(ThreeDRay.java:13)
>       at ThreeDRayRunner.main(ThreeDRayRunner.java:41)

Also, in the runner I ask the user to input the integer that will be stored in the 3D Array. To do this I ask for the size and print the 3D Array when is empty and after the given numbers are added. This is my code for that:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

    out.print("How many matrices are you going to enter? ");
    int s = keyboard.nextInt();


    int[][][] d3= new int [s][][];

    for(int i = 0; i < S; i++)
    {
        out.print("What is the size of the matrix " + i + " ? ");
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();

        int[][] mat = new int[size][size];
        out.println();

        for(int r=0; r<mat.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c=0; c<mat[r].length; c++)
            {
                out.print("Enter a value for spot " + r + " - " + c );
               mat[r][c]=keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }

       out.println("The array before setting mat at spot "+i);


       ThreeDRay.print(d3);

       d3[i] = mat;


        out.println("The array after setting mat at spot "+i);

       ThreeDRay.print(d3);
```

Comment: Why don't you initialize the matrix, only after you have all the sizes. First you input for s, and then for size. And only after you have both values you do  int[][][] array = new int[s][size][size];

Answer (score 0):

You are not instantiating the 2nd and 3rd dimensions of `d3` Did you mean to do this line before your first print?

```
d3[i] = mat;
```

So it would look like this:

```
d3[i] = mat;

out.println("The array before setting mat at spot "+i);
ThreeDRay.print(d3);
```

Follow up:

It looks like you actually didn't want to set d3[i] before your first print. In that case make sure you 3 dimensions for d3 are all non-null since your print is going to print all of them and not only the one that you set to mat. Initialize your 2nd and 3rd dimensions (to 0) before you start.

```
int[][][] d3= new int [s][][];
for (int i=0; i < d3.length ;++i){
  d3[i] = new int[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Even by replacing the code with what you wrote I keep getting a Null Pointer Exemption. However, I still want to print the empty array before the one that has the integers on it. I have edited my desired output on the question to be more specific @Amin J

Comment: Ok it looks like you want a different behavior. I updated the post, try that.

Comment: Still getting the NullPointer Error when I try to print it

Comment: I have tested it. It should work. Can you up update your code that is still throwing the exception?